# How do I stop a repeated action?

Tags: c#

This is for C#.

Ok so I'm coding a very basic money-managing program. You have an account with money in it and you deposit funds into it or you withdraw funds from it.

Obviously you don't want to accidentally perform the same transaction twice, so I'm trying to throw an InvalidOperationException when a transaction has already been attempted in the past and to specify the reason for this exception. But I have no idea how to go about this.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void Execute(decimal amount)
{
    if (_executed)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    if (_balance <= amount)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(" insufficient funds");
    }
    if (!_success)
    {
        this._balance -= amount;
        _success = true;
    }
}
```

Conceptually I imagine a transaction's unique 'identity' can be stored somewhere and if one attempts another transaction I can use a command that says something along the lines of "if 'unique code' exists in this place then show error. Or else, continue with transaction". Any other way to go about it? I have very little experience coding, I'm in my 1st year at uni.

Comment: What do you understand your "transaction" to be?

Comment: you can make transaction id as unique/primary key.

Comment: You could compare the new attempted transaction against the history of recent transactions. If there is a transaction with identical amount and identical destination, you could trigger a warning. Be aware, that it could make sense to repeat certain transactions. These could be distinguished by varying the subject text.

Comment: ChrisBD: I don't understand what you mean by that. The transaction is just a number. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Axel Kemper: That's exactly what I'm attempting to do. That is the goal of this question. I just don't have the coding knowledge to do it. Googling this turns up nothing and so I'm unable to learn how to do this. Can you please show me how to code for this?

Comment: Side note: I suggest adding a *message* to `InvalidOperationException` why the operation is invalid one: `throw new InvalidOperationException("Synchronization failure: withdrawing is in the process");`

Comment: Deepak Mishra: How can I make a transaction id as a unique/primary key?

Answer (score 1):

In order to identify repeat transactions, you first have to determine what constitute a transaction. If you only keep a dollar amount, it will not be enough, as you can buy multiple items with the same price.

So, you need to introduce a class for your transactions. In this class, you can generate a unique ID to ensure a transaction is only processed once:

```
using System;
public class Transaction {
    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public Transaction(decimal amount){
        Amount = amount;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Generate a random, unique enough identifier
    }
}
```

Then, in your execute, you can save executed transaction and error if it was already run. I will use a set here to store past transactions:

```
using System.Collection.Generic; // for the HashSet
public class Account {
    private HashSet<Guid> pastTransactions = new HashSet<Guid>();
    private decimal _balance;

    public bool TryExecute(Transaction transaction) {
        if (pastTransactions.Contains(transaction.Id))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction already executed");
        }
        if (_balance <= transaction.Amount)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this._balance -= transaction.Amount;
        pastTransactions.Add(transaction.Id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this example, I generate a Guid for each transaction object, which can be used to avoid a transaction being run twice due to a bug in the code. Note that I throw an exception for this case, but not for the low balance issue.

In general, exceptions should be reserved for, as their name imply, exceptional issues, not as a general control flow of the program. trying to run a transaction on an account with a too low balance is not something I would consider Exceptional in a budgeting program, it is better to reject the transaction in this case with a `TryExecute`returning a status for success or failure. Here I used a boolean for simplicity, but you could also return a more complex result type, with more details about the failure if there are multiple possible failure state.

---

This implementation with a unique Guid for each transaction is usefull if you want to prevent bugs in the program causing a transaction to be executed multiple times, but will not really help in case the user enter the same transaction manually. To prevent this, we can use a more complex transaction class:

```
public class Transaction {
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public decimal Amount { get; }
    public string Description { get; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; }

    public Transaction(decimal amount, 
                       string description, 
                       DateTimeOffset timestamp){
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Amount = amount;
        Description = description;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Then, you can search your past transactions for one with the same amount, description and timestamp, failing the execution if a matching one is found. In that case, I think a failure state is again more appropriate than an exception, as we are dealing with a probable user error.

Comment: In addition, if you have to have 2 systems interact in order to send transactions then you should take a look at the Two Generals Problem. EX. Amazon communicating the purchase to a bank. It will give you a good idea of how to handle unique transactions.